# Can you add multiple custom liquids without shared content in a single shopify2.0 template?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Can you add multiple custom liquids with unique content in a single shopify template or a page? How would you implement this. thankyou

1. tried adding different custom liquids with different html content but the first liquids content shows up in second
2. created a custom liquid that is only showing up in layout but not in template

Comment: Could you provide more information how you want this to work? You can create a shopify page template and use this for different shopify pages with different page title and contents.